# Getting an external list of ip and turning in to variable dic in Python

Tags: python, windows

How can I do this:

Enter on this website (http://www.samair.ru/proxy/time-01.htm) and get the list of the ip address and turn it to a dictionary variable?

whit these code in particular, I only can get the first ip of the website

```
ip = urllib.urlopen('http://www.samair.ru/proxy/time-01.htm').read()
clientIp = re.search("(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)", ip).group()

print clientIp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findall` instead of `search`:

```
ip = urllib.urlopen('http://www.samair.ru/proxy/time-01.htm').read()
clientIp = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", ip)
```

Note the “raw” string `r"…"` that prevents interpretation of the backslashes as escape character.

This gives you a list of strings containing the IP addresses. To turn it into a dictionary you need key–value pairs.

Comment: how can I do it with the ports too? I'm trying to add ':\d+\' to the the port, but it's turning the 'ip' variable to string

Comment: The page uses JavaScript to hide the port number, you have to “decode” it first. For example, one of the line reads `<td>75.21.47.2<script type="text/javascript">document.write(":"+t+z+t+z)</script></td>`, with constants `t` and `z` defined somewhere. This is much harder and cannot be done with a simple regular expression search; please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [re.findall()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of re.search()